# WordPress display only the posts who have a certain parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I would like to query posts based on specific `category_parent id`. This is used as a filtering function for the users to filter posts based on a parent category type. I have multiple categories who have multiple children categories. For example, Fruits is the parent category, then children categories can be red, blue, orange. Vegetables is a parent category, and it also has red, blue and orange child categories. I would like users to filter and see all the vegetable child categories or all the fruits child categories.

I am using category id instead of slug in my case. 
For example, I want to query all the posts whose parent category is 17 and 19. (dummy).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'additional_query', 1, 1);       
function additional_query( $query ){
     $tax_query = array(
                array( 
                    "taxonomy" => "category", 
                    "field" => 'term_id',
                    "terms" => array(17, 19)
                )
            );
            $query->set( "tax_query", $tax_query );
}
```

However, when I do `get_categories()`, the posts returned still contains other categories whose parent is not 17 and 19. 
How should I approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: this looks like a duplicate: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169469/get-posts-from-child-categories-with-parent-category-id

Comment: sorry about the duplication, but that solution doesn't work for me though. I realize however I change the query, the get_categories() function always returns all the terms, which shows the query does not work in filtering out the parent categories.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'additional_query', 1, 1);       
function additional_query( $query ){

            $query->set( "category__and",array(17, 19));

}
```